# Visual Basic difference between 'Not a = b' and 'a <> b'

Tags: vb.net, optimization

The title really says it all. In VB.NET is there a difference between these  statements when checking for **value equality**

```
Dim notEqualsCompare as Boolean = Not a = b
Dim angleBracCompare as Boolean = a <> b
```

I usually use 'Not a = b' just because it reads better.
I read the '<>' operator as 'is less or greater than' which only really makes sense for numeric values, but from my brief testing they behave the same.

Is there ever a situation where one is preferable?

Comment: Simply put, they both are same, it's just what you prefer as your weapon of choice :)

Comment: I read '<>' as 'not equal' and it works for both numeric and alphanumeric.

Comment: Opinion based, but some teams/developers stop using `Not` operator because of bad readability with variables which names starts with `isSomething` or `canSomething`

Comment: I usually try to do as less as possible if statement that starts with a Not, it's less confusing.

Comment: @fabio Now you mention it, I've ran into this before. Another situation where using Not can get confusing is in long statements with multiple And and/or Or statements.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, they should always be functionally equivalent.

As mentioned in one of the other answers, `Not a = b` is logically two separate operations.  You may trust that the compiler will optimize that for you, but, regardless, most programmers would agree that, if a language has an operator to do what you want, you should generally use that feature of the language rather than using multiple operations to accomplish the same result.  If you don't like the language, choose another language.  But if you're going to use VB, it's best to get used to it and take advantage of it's syntax.

Technically, though, it's worth mentioning that they aren't *necessarily* the same.  All three of the following lines could technically have different results:

```
result = Not a = b
result = a <> b
result = Not a.Equals(b)
```

The reason why they can be different is because VB allows you to override the `=` operator (equality test, not assignment), the `<>` operator, the `Not` operator, and the `Equals` method.  So, even though it would be horrendous to override those things and provide differing functionality for each, it is technically possible.  For obvious reasons, the ["official" guidelines from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/equality-operators) recommend that they always work consistent to each other.

Consider:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim a As New Crazy()
    Dim b As New Crazy()
    Console.WriteLine(a = b)            ' False
    Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b))      ' True
    Console.WriteLine(a <> b)           ' False
    Console.WriteLine(Not a)            ' "Opposite"
    Console.WriteLine(Not a = b)        ' True
    Console.WriteLine(Not a.Equals(b))  ' False
End Sub

Private Class Crazy
    Public Shared Operator <>(x As Crazy, y As Crazy) As Boolean
        Return False
    End Operator

    Public Shared Operator =(x As Crazy, y As Crazy) As Boolean
        Return False
    End Operator

    Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function

    Public Shared Operator Not(value As Crazy) As String
        Return "Opposite"
    End Operator
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

They both produce the same answer, however, `a <> b` would probably be more efficient. The reason being is that when the compiler comes to "Not a = b", the compiler must first do the comparison (`a = b`), then it must use clock cycles to flip that login (`Not`). When doing `a <> b`, the compiler would only have to do the comparison and then it's done. Look at this chart:

---

```
a <> b    ' One Operation
```

---

---

```
c = a = b      ' One Operation
Not c          ' Another Operation
```

Comment: Odds are that the compiler is going to optimize this down to a single operation, regardless of which way it is coded.

Comment: @BradleyUffner From the look of it, the compiler actual turns both forms into two comparisons, since CIL seems to lack a "not equal" instruction, i.e. both are compiled to `(a = b) = 0`.